# How to utilize Visual Studio 2015 to program Android apps using existing Java/Android code?

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio-2015

With the new Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (VS15) finally released, it comes with the ability to program not only for Windows, but for Android and iOS devices as well.

I have a couple Android apps, and I maintain them using Android Studio. In my opinion, VS15 IDE is stronger than Android Studio, and I would like to migrate my existing apps, and future projects to VS15.

My question is: can I, somehow, use my existing Java code for my Android apps in Visual Studio, or Visual Studio, as it is right now, only supports C# for Android apps?

All I find is creating Android apps using C# (which is great), but I find nothing about re-using existing Java code for Android, and even better, if Java and C# code can be mixed (to use libraries I have created in Java for my Android projects).

Note that I am not asking about porting the existing Android app/code into a Windows app, yet.

Comment: You cannot write native app using java on VS, can use only c#. You also cannot mix both together.

Comment: It is possible to write java application using this  [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93) though

Comment: Here is a paid tool https://visualgdb.com/